# Plugin com.tibco.plugins:bw6-maven-plugin:1.1.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved - BW6 maven plugin build issue

Tags: businessworks, tibco-business-works

I am using BWCE Studio (2.1.0), BW6 maven plugin (1.1.0). When I try to build a BWCE application from Jenkins using the BW6 maven plugin, I get following error:

Jenkins Console Output:::

```
Started by user admin
```

Building in workspace C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\bwce-app-build

> C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
>   Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
>   C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe config remote.origin.url _https://github.com/RajibBiswasTibco/BWCEJenkins.git # timeout=10
>   Fetching upstream changes from _https://github.com/RajibBiswasTibco/BWCEJenkins.git
>   C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe --version # timeout=10
>   C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe fetch --tags --progress _https://github.com/RajibBiswasTibco/BWCEJenkins.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
>   C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe rev-parse "refs/remotes/origin/master^{commit}" # timeout=10
>   C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe rev-parse "refs/remotes/origin/origin/master^{commit}" # timeout=10
>   Checking out Revision 8d093265f7e348f79e506c905be3702abe41ec33 (refs/remotes/origin/master)
>   C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
>   C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe checkout -f 8d093265f7e348f79e506c905be3702abe41ec33
>   C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe rev-list 8d093265f7e348f79e506c905be3702abe41ec33 # timeout=10
>   Parsing POMs
>   Established TCP socket on 53491
>   [bwce-test-app.application.parent] $ java -cp "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\plugins\maven-plugin\WEB-INF\lib\maven33-agent-1.8.1.jar;C:\sw\apache-maven-3.3.9\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar;C:\sw\apache-maven-3.3.9/conf/logging" jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven33Main C:\sw\apache-maven-3.3.9 "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\war\WEB-INF\lib\remoting-2.62.jar" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\plugins\maven-plugin\WEB-INF\lib\maven33-interceptor-1.8.1.jar" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\plugins\maven-plugin\WEB-INF\lib\maven3-interceptor-commons-1.8.1.jar" 53491
>   <===[JENKINS REMOTING CAPACITY]===>channel started
>   Executing Maven:  -B -f C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\bwce-app-build\bwce-test-app.application.parent\pom.xml clean package
>   [INFO] Scanning for projects...
>   [WARNING] The POM for com.tibco.plugins:bw6-maven-plugin:jar:1.1.0 is missing, no dependency information available
>   [ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
>   [ERROR] Unresolveable build extension: Plugin com.tibco.plugins:bw6-maven-plugin:1.1.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failure to find com.tibco.plugins:bw6-maven-plugin:jar:1.1.0 in _https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced @ 
>   [ERROR] Unknown packaging: bwmodule @ com.tibco.bw:bwce-test-app:[unknown-version], C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\bwce-app-build\bwce-test-app\pom.xml, line 12, column 14
>   [ERROR] Unresolveable build extension: Plugin com.tibco.plugins:bw6-maven-plugin:1.1.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failure to find com.tibco.plugins:bw6-maven-plugin:jar:1.1.0 in _https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced @ 
>   [ERROR] Unknown packaging: bwear @ com.tibco.bw:bwce-test-app.application:[unknown-version], C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\bwce-app-build\bwce-test-app.application\pom.xml, line 12, column 14
>    @ 
>   [ERROR] The build could not read 2 projects -> [Help 1]
>   [ERROR]
>   [ERROR]   The project com.tibco.bw:bwce-test-app:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT (C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\bwce-app-build\bwce-test-app\pom.xml) has 2 errors
>   [ERROR]     Unresolveable build extension: Plugin com.tibco.plugins:bw6-maven-plugin:1.1.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failure to find com.tibco.plugins:bw6-maven-plugin:jar:1.1.0 in _https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 2]
>   [ERROR]     Unknown packaging: bwmodule @ com.tibco.bw:bwce-test-app:[unknown-version], C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\bwce-app-build\bwce-test-app\pom.xml, line 12, column 14
>   [ERROR]
>   [ERROR]   The project com.tibco.bw:bwce-test-app.application:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT (C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\bwce-app-build\bwce-test-app.application\pom.xml) has 2 errors
>   [ERROR]     Unresolveable build extension: Plugin com.tibco.plugins:bw6-maven-plugin:1.1.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failure to find com.tibco.plugins:bw6-maven-plugin:jar:1.1.0 in _https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 2]
>   [ERROR]     Unknown packaging: bwear @ com.tibco.bw:bwce-test-app.application:[unknown-version], C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\bwce-app-build\bwce-test-app.application\pom.xml, line 12, column 14
>   [ERROR] 
>   [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
>   [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
>   [ERROR] 
>   [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
>   [ERROR] [Help 1] _http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
>   [ERROR] [Help 2] _http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginManagerException
>   channel stopped
>   Finished: FAILURE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the maven local repositoty is different betweeen jenkins and maven.
[image: Configuration Jenkins]

You have 2 option:

1. You will update the configuration option(`setting.xml`) for maven in jenkins.

or

2. You copy this path `C:\Users\$USER_NAME\.m2\repository\com\tibco\plugins\bw6-maven-plugin` in the local repository for jenkins.